# Unable to Process array of arrays of floats with rapidjson

Tags: json, unreal-engine4, rapidjson

I want to parse the following array of arrays using rapidjson. My code environment is VS2019 with Unreal Engine v4.24.3. I am new to C++.

```
const char* json = "{ \"data\":[[0.0,1.1],[2.1,3.1]] }";
```

I have already referred to [Rapidjson , get a value inside an array of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170718/rapidjson-get-a-value-inside-an-array-of-another-array) & [Processing arrays of arrays of integer with rapidjson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443829/processing-arrays-of-arrays-of-integer-with-rapidjson)

For the **integer** array of arrays following code works just fine.

```
const char* json = "{ \"data\":[[0,1],[2,3]] }";

Document d;
d.Parse(json);

const rapidjson::Value& b = d["data"];

for (rapidjson::SizeType i = 0; i < b.Size(); i++)
{
    const rapidjson::Value& c = b[i];
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("%d: Test Data"), c[rapidjson::SizeType(0)].GetInt());
}
```

Returns->

```
LogTemp: 0: Test Data //Expected values
LogTemp: 2: Test Data
```

But for the array of arrays with **Float** values, the following code does not work.

```
const char* json = "{ \"data\":[[0.5,1.1],[2.1,3.1]] }";

Document d;
d.Parse(json);

const rapidjson::Value& b = d["data"];

for (rapidjson::SizeType i = 0; i < b.Size(); i++)
{
    const rapidjson::Value& c = b[i];
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("%d: test Data"), c[rapidjson::SizeType(0)].GetFloat());
}
```

returns ->

```
LogTemp: 0: test Data
LogTemp: -1073741824: test Data
```

How can I figure this out? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

floating point specifier %f should be used for the float data type.

```
const char* json = "{ \"data\":[[0.5,1.1],[2.1,3.1]] }";

Document d;
d.Parse(json);

const rapidjson::Value& b = d["data"];

for (rapidjson::SizeType i = 0; i < b.Size(); i++)
{
    const rapidjson::Value& c = b[i];
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("%f: test Data"), c[rapidjson::SizeType(0)].GetFloat());
}
```